# Push to Login page if user is not logged in, else let inside

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a simple Login page that routes me to home page.

In my content page I want the default path to be `/`, and for login `/login`. I want to push user to `/login` route based on a conditional `isLoggedIn`, at the moment without state manager just for testing purposes. Not sure if I am setting this up correctly, maybe I am doing this completely wrong? I want also to be able to access different routes after being logged in.

```js
function App() {
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
    <div className="app">
      <Header />
      <div class="app__body">
        {isLoggedIn
        ? <Route path="/" element={<Content />}></Route>
        : <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
      }
      </div>
    </div>
    </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I am getting this error

```
index.tsx:19 Uncaught Error: [div] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a couple of different factors are at play here.

First of all, the only `Route` components are allowed as children of the `Routes` component and so that's the reason you're getting the following error:

> index.tsx:19 Uncaught Error: [div] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>

Next, one way of going about it is to just render a redirect in the element property of the root path if the user is not signed in.

```js
import { Router, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const isLoggedIn = true;
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <div class="app__body">
          {/*The only children of Routes should be Route components*/}
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />

            {/* Render a redirect to login if the user is not signed in */}
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={isLoggedIn ? <Content /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
            />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```